# stat structure error(fstat system call)

Tags: c, unix

I am having this code snippet:

```
struct stat *fileData;
if((fd=open("abc.txt",O_RDONLY)==-1)
      perror("file not opened");
if((fstat(fd,fileData)==-1)
      perror("stucture not filled");
printf("%d",fileData.st_size);
```

It shows me error:

```
 request for member ‘st_size’ in something not a structure or union
```

I tried using `stat` also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it stands you're writing (`fstat` is) to an uninitialized pointer and then trying to read from it as if it were a `struct stat`. You should change your code to:

```
struct stat fileData;
if((fstat(fd, &fileData) == -1)
              ^
```

Alternatively you could `malloc` memory to `fileData` and then use `fileData->st_size`. This would be less elegant (you'd have to `free` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Your `fileData` struct is a pointer. `fileData.st_size` would have to be `fileData->st.size` or `(*fileDate).st_size`

However, stat() expects you to provide the storage for a struct stat, you have to do

```
struct stat fileData; // <---change to this
if((fd=open("abc.txt",O_RDONLY)==-1)
      perror("file not opened");
if((fstat(fd,&fileData)==-1)  // <---change to this
      perror("stucture not filled");
printf("%d",fileData.st_size);
```